# FluentAssertions comparing contents of lists instead of lists themselves

Tags: .net, fluent-assertions

I have two objects (instances of the same class) with a bunch of properties, some of them lists of other objects.

```
class A  {
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public IList<C> cs { get; set; }
}
```

I want to compare these using the [FluentAssertions library](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/), and make sure they have the same properties, so I add

```
first.ShouldHave().AllProperties().EqualTo(second);
```

but then I get an error that

> Expected property cs to have value <C, C, C> but found <C, C, C>

In other words, when comparing properties that are lists, it does a reference-equals, which obviously fails in this case.

How do I tell FluentAssertions to assert that *the properties of the elements in the lists* are equal, rather than the lists themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supported as of version 1.7.0. Read the release notes here. http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2012/01/fluent-assertions-170-has-been-released.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to upgrade at the moment - that will have to go through the chain of decisions in our development team first. But the fact that I would have to upgrade to get the functionality answers my question anyway =) Thanks!

Comment: Well, version 1.7.0 is backwards compatible with 1.6.0, that's why we use Semantic Versioning :-)

Comment: Good to know! It's still not my decision, but it'll be easier to convince the project manager =)